# Sanitise .csv before importing into Google BigQuery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I have bunch of big csv files to be imported to BigQuery. Some of them contain rows with wrongly formatted data, some rows need to be modified (e.g. summarize two columns from the row) etc. What is the best way to clean this up? Should i just upload all the dirty data into a table and then run a Cloud Function script on each row to sanitize it, modify if needed and store into another "clean" table? Or should i do this with App Engine? Or may be i should make App Engine to process each csv and insert row by row into BigQuery?

**Update:**

I haven't found a way to run transformations/validations within GBQ without pulling this data to the app, which invokes it. For example, an API server (Kubernetes Engine) is responsible for file uploading. Then it triggers files import. But then what? NodeJS SDK has CRUD operations, but it requires to pull data from GBQ, which is severely inefficient. Is there way to trigger changes within GBQ?

To be specific, here are some examples of csv rows transformations that i need:

- convert String `$123,50` into integer (float or whatever) `123.5`.
- math operations on two or columns from a single row. E.g. i have `price` and `number` and i need to get `total_price`, which is `price * number`.

Comment: I see three questions here: 1) how to modify wrongly formatted data & 2)where better to make it happen - in CSV before loading to GBQ or in GBQ after loading from GCS 3) how to better orchestrate this process for big number of files. Which exactly question you are actually asking? I would recommend reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: #2. I don't have big number of files, just 10 files. 20 to 100mb each. But this procedure is repeatable, so it needs to be automated.

Comment: got it. I would definitely vote for making this in GBQ as it is most flexible and  fast way. you just load your files as is and then use BigQuery magic to transform your data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Cloud Dataprep, https://cloud.google.com/dataprep

This product is designed for someone just like you.  It provides an interface to build an ETL recipe,  and then will use Dataflow to execute the ETL, ongoing or one time use.

Answer (score 1):

> where better to make it happen - in CSV before loading to GBQ or in GBQ after loading from GCS?

I recommend making this in GBQ as it is most flexible and  fast way.
You just load your files as is and then use BigQuery magic to transform your data

As for automation - you can use any client of your preference to script the process

> convert String $123,50 into integer (float or whatever) 123.5.
>   math operations on two or columns from a single row. E.g. i have price and number and i need to get total_price, which is price * number.

See example below  (for BigQuery Standard SQL)

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourTable` AS (
  SELECT '$123,50' AS price, 5 AS number UNION ALL
  SELECT '$1,99', 99
)
SELECT 
  CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(price, ',', '.'), '$', '') AS FLOAT64) AS price,
  CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(price, ',', '.'), '$', '') AS FLOAT64) * number AS total_price
FROM `project.dataset.yourTable`
```

or, to avoid redundant `CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(price, ',', '.'), '$', '') AS FLOAT64)` you can use below approach

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourTable` AS (
  SELECT '$123,50' AS price, 5 AS number UNION ALL
  SELECT '$1,99', 99
)
SELECT 
  price,
  price * number AS total_price
FROM `project.dataset.yourTable`, 
UNNEST([CAST(REPLACE(REPLACE(price, ',', '.'), '$', '') AS FLOAT64)]) AS price
```

in both cases  - result is as below

```sql
price   total_price  
123.5   617.5    
1.99    197.01
```

Comment: Thank you! Could you clarify something, pls: what magic? I haven't found a way to run transformations/validations within GBQ without pulling this data to the app, which invokes it. For example, an API server (Kubernetes) is responsible for file uploading. Then it triggers files import. But then what? NodeJS SDK has CRUD operations, but it requires to pull data from GBQ, which is severely inefficient. Is there way to trigger changes within GBQ?

Comment: Now you are asking about how to do transformation in GBQ (which is #1 out of those three I mentioned in my original comment! if you provide example of what kind of transformation you need to make - I or someone else here will be able to show you the `Magic` of BigQuery :o) Again - please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Like Mikhail said, just load your files in and then transform the data directly in BigQuery. When he says "magic" he means just simply using SQL to transform it.

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant "most flexible and fast way.". That's really not true. if you have a csv file with quotes or enters (new lines) in the string column, then we're doomed. No matter what you try, BQ will just not accept the format. where as google sheet will.